# I need the source code to build a ubuntu phone rom for the moto x

Tags: ubuntu-touch

If i could get the source code for ubuntu phone os, i could compile a build of the os for the moto x, which a good number of people want.

Comment: You should be asking this at [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com)